# cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket

Tags: java, android, sslhandshakeexception

This is my function (SERVER_URL) is https

```
    public void Register(String username, String Email) {
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    requestParams.put("task", "register");
    requestParams.put("name", username);
    requestParams.put("email", Email);
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.setTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    client.post(SERVER_URL, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // called before request is started
            Log.d(TAG, SERVER_URL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

        }
    });
}
```

Return a error :

```
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x9d665200: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:543)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:409)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:479)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:66)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
10-25 00:30:23.495 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:879)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-25 00:30:23.496 27342-28054/com.webdigitronix.shoppingday W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)